# Vue: out-in, old text fades out, but new text doesn't fade in, appears abruptly

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuejs3

I found this codepen that makes old text fade out and new text to appear: https://codepen.io/cythilya/pen/EXxved

**html**:

```html
<div id="app">
  <button @click="show = !show">Click Me!</button>
  <transition mode="out-in">
    <div class="block" v-if="show">Block 1</div>
    <p class="block" v-else>Block 
      2</p>
  </transition>
</div>
```

**css**:

```css
body { font-family: 微軟正黑體; }
button { margin-bottom: 10px; }

#app {
  padding: 10px;
}

.block {
  background: #999;
  color: #fff;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.v-leave { opacity: 1; }
.v-leave-active { transition: opacity 2s }
.v-leave-to { opacity: 0; }
.v-enter { opacity: 0; }
.v-enter-active  { transition: opacity 2s }
.v-enter-to { opacity: 1; }
```

**js**:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    show: true
  }
});
```

However when I try to use it with `Vue 3`, it fades out the old text, but doesn't fade in the new text - the new text appears abruptly: https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-resonance-yjfl72?file=/src/App.vue

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <button @click="show = !show">Click Me!</button>
    <transition mode="out-in">
      <div class="block" v-if="show">Block 1</div>
      <p class="block" v-else>Block 2</p>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorldVue from "./components/HelloWorld.vue";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HelloWorld: HelloWorldVue,
  },

  data() {
    return { show: true };
  },
};
</script>

<style>
body {
  font-family: 微軟正黑體;
}
button {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#app {
  padding: 10px;
}

.block {
  background: #999;
  color: #fff;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.v-leave {
  opacity: 1;
}
.v-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 2s;
}
.v-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
.v-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}
.v-enter-active {
  transition: opacity 2s;
}
.v-enter-to {
  opacity: 1;
}
</style>
```

Why did the behavior change? How should I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vue 3, the CSS class names were adjusted, `.v-enter` is now `.v-enter-from`:

```css
.v-enter-from {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Here it is in a [playround](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Answer (score 2):

change `.v-enter` to `.v-enter-from`

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <button @click="show = !show">Click Me!</button>
    <transition mode="out-in">
      <div class="block" v-if="show">Block 1</div>
      <p class="block" v-else>Block 2</p>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return { show: true };
  },
};
</script>

<style>
body {
  font-family: 微軟正黑體;
}
button {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#app {
  padding: 10px;
}

.block {
  background: #999;
  color: #fff;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.v-leave-from {
  opacity: 1;
}
.v-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 2s;
}
.v-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
.v-enter-from {
  opacity: 0;
}
.v-enter-active {
  transition: opacity 2s;
}
.v-enter-to {
  opacity: 1;
}
</style>
```

demo: https://livecodes.io/?x=id/frekdfs4eg2